# detect browser window resize without event

Tags: javascript, angular, web, browser

I would like to know if, in Javascript in general (and in Angular in particular), it is possible to check if the browser window has been previously resized by the user, e.g. if the user has landed on my page on an already resized browser.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I dont think so, that does not make sense to me. Why would you want this?

Comment: Best I can think of is to check `window.screen.width` and compare it with `window.innerWidth`.

Comment: great trick ! thanks :)